# Add data-th text .before an item

Tags: html, jquery, html-table

I am having an issue with a WordPress plugin, which creates a table, but leaves out the TH info on mobile. I want the "data-th" text/data to show before the table data.

Example of what I want to achieve
`<*h4 class="someClassName">Article Name</h4*><br>BBD4<br><*h4 class="someClassName2">NFF</h4*><br>000-0000` 
etc.

I want to use jQuery to grab `data-th` and insert (".table-value").before.

```
<tr id="table-row-576" class="table-row even" role="row">
<td data-th="Article name" class="table-value-at table-value">BBD482</td>
<td data-th="NFF" class="table-value-at table-value">111-0000</td>
<td data-th="Width" class="table-value-at table-value">250 - 370 mm</td>
<td data-th="weight" class="table-value-at table-value">13 kg</td>
<td data-th="Quantity" class="table-value-qt table-value"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I can't tell what you mean. Can you rewrite with what you have *first* and what you want second. Plz format the 'what i want to achieve' part like the 2nd part of your current question. Remove the asterisks if they are not actually part of the result. Also show us what you have tried.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You might consider adjusting this via CSS instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following CSS solution.

```css
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  table.myTable thead th {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Article Name</th>
      <th>NFF</th>
      <th>Width</th>
      <th>Weight</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="table-row-576" class="table-row even" role="row">
      <td data-th="Article name" class="table-value-at table-value">BBD482</td>
      <td data-th="NFF" class="table-value-at table-value">111-0000</td>
      <td data-th="Width" class="table-value-at table-value">250 - 370 mm</td>
      <td data-th="weight" class="table-value-at table-value">13 kg</td>
      <td data-th="Quantity" class="table-value-qt table-value"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

To see this in action, display the snippet in Full PAge and then change the window size. Once it is less than 480 pixels, like a Mobile Phone, it will make each TH a block display, so they are each on their own line.

You can do this with jQuery as well. It just requires an event to check the `window` or `document` width. CSS will just do it regardless.

With WordPress, it is often best to make standard HTML elements. So if you're building a Table with jQuery, make sure to create all the proper elements. To adjust the look and feel, simply use CSS, either directly inline (preferred) or via CSS. This way WP can still apply it's themes and styling. When themes get updated, you won't lose all your customizations.

Comment: Thank you @twisty for bringing me back to CSS, that solved my problem. It did not work as intended when using display: block;. But using

`.table-value[data-th="Artikkelnavn"]:before {
  content: "Artikkelnavn: " !important;
  font-weight: 700;
 }`

It was quite a manual job, as there were a few variations, but it did what I wanted it to.